# I'm currently learning Solidity and how to develop Dapps on Ethereum blockchain, is my understanding correct?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

So basically, what's happening is, a Smart Contract is the business logic/backend code you write for your decentralized app, or Dapp, and deploy it to the Ethereum blockchain. Then, whenever you want to perform computation on the Dapp (like changing a variable or executing a function that changes a certain parameter of the Smart Contract), you send a Contract Transaction to the Ethereum network which routes it to the appropriate Node, and alongside with that, you send some Ether.

A volunteer on the Ethereum network lends their computing power to add that Contract Transaction to the Ethereum blockchain, "like mining", and receives the ether you sent as a reward for completing the task. This is much like how Bitcoin mining works, except, in this case, the miners lend their hardware to perform computing tasks for your Dapp.

So what is ultimately happening is, you change data on your Dapp by adding entries into the blockchain itself, every time you call a function that changes a variable/data inside the Smart Contract instance? So you could say, this is like an AWS server, except the computing power doesn't come from Amazon but from regular people looking to mine some Ether?

Comment: I would say that's a pretty good understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a good understanding and I want to add some more facts.

You can also simply get data from smart contract functions, not only change the variable/data. That kind of functions have `view` keyword in the function signature in solidity code and when you call these functions, you don't need to pay Ethers, because they don't change the data, but they simply gets the data.